# Using Azure, how could I run a short-lived Docker container on a schedule whilst maintaining a static IP?

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances, azure-container-apps, azure-container-app-jobs

Relatively new to azure so apologies if this is obvious, but I am trying to run a docker container hosted within a private azure container registry on a daily cron. This container essentially fetches data from an externally hosted end point that uses IP whitelisting in order to access.

I have scoured through the azure help pages and have found something that would fit the bill: Azure Container App Job. This would be ideal as it would fire up the container at a given time every day on a CRON, process the data, and finish. However as I have mentioned, I am needing this container to have a static IP in order to access this end point but see nothing about assosciating these scheduled jobs with an existing network or static IP.

Is there something I have missed? Is there a service that can handle this outside of Container Apps?

I am also trying to avoid creating and maintaining a VM for something that would execute for roughly a minute every day, as it is only one container that would run.

Comment: container app is a good option. i would use the nat gateway option to make sure you can keep the ip if you have to delete/recreate you're container app env: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/networking?tabs=azure-cli#nat-gateway-integration